# How can I filter alarm data in Thingsboard alarm widget?

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I have an alarm widget that shows list of alarms with their severity (CRITICAL, WARNING), I need to make it only shows specific severity without change the DataSource, for example only the 'CRITICAL' alarms, How can I do that? any help will be very helpful.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the alarm widget you may need to change the severity related checks and update function handlers accordingly.

Here are couple of links that should be helpful

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#alarm-widget

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-clear-alarms/